# How to properly multi-thread a collection of independent tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm using this code to divide up a few hundred tasks between different CPU cores.

```
    final List<Throwable> errors = Collections.synchronizedList(Lists.<Throwable>newArrayList());

    final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

    for (...) {

        pool.execute(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {

            try {

                // TASK HERE

            } catch (Throwable e) {
                errors.add(e);
            }

        }});

    }

    pool.shutdown();
    try {
        pool.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.DAYS); // wait "indefinitely"
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) throw Exceptions.wrap(errors.get(0)); // TODO multi-exception
```

It works, but it's not nice.

- There is no version of `awaitTermination` without timeout, which is what I want.
- I need to do my own error collecting.

What is the proper/common way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of a thread pool is to reuse threads. You should create it on application startup, outside of your code that creates tasks, and inject it. There is no need to shut down the pool after adding tasks. You do that when your application is shutting down.

To run a collection of tasks, use `ExecutorService.invokeAll`. To get the results afterwards, call `get` on each of the returned `Futures`. It will rethrow any exception that the task threw, so you can collect it afterwards.

Comment: I shut down the pool because otherwise `awaitTermination` won't work.

Comment: You don't need to do `awaitTermination` either.

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom if you call future.get(), it will block until the task is finished, so when you shutdown the pool everything will already be terminated.

Comment: I do, because the code below this depends on the tasks being completed. Anyway, `invokeAll` is closer to what I need.

Comment: @assylias Yes, but as you can see in the code above, there is no reference to `Future` or `Future.get()`

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom the answer suggests using futures instead of using the code in your question.

Comment: @assylias Yes, but I'm responding to comments about the code I already had.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a future to do the error handling:

```
final List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<Future>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    futures.add(pool.submit(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {
            // TASK HERE
    }}));

}

for (Future f : futures) {
    try {
        f.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        //something bad happened in your runnable
    }
}

//when you are done with the executor

pool.shutdown();
try {
    pool.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.DAYS); // wait "indefinitely"
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to submit each Runnable, get a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) back, and then call [get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29) on each Future.

When you call `get()`, you'll either get the result of the Runnable, or the exception that it encountered.